# UNIX While Loop Using grep

Tags: unix

I am trying to create a while loop that checks my data file for a particular string $username and if a duplicate of it is found in the data file, a number is added to the end of it. This is what I have and for some reason I get an error "too many arguments" for the line containing the while loop. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    tput cup 3 12
    echo "Enter the first name of the user: "
    tput cup 3 47; read firstName
    tput cup 4 12; echo "Enter the last name of the user: "
    tput cup 4 45; read lastName
    username=${firstName:0:1}${lastName:0:4}
    i=0
    while [ -n $(grep -q -F "$username" capstonedata.txt) ]
    do
            let i=$i+1
            username=$username$i
    done
    userdata=${firstName}":"${lastName}":"${username}
    echo $userdata | tr [a-z] [A-Z] >> capstonedata.txt
```

Comment: I have come to realize a few of my mistakes but it still is not doing what I mean for it to
                   '      i=0
        while [ -n $(grep -q -F "$username" capstonedata.txt) ]
        do
                let i=$i+1
                username=$username$i
        done '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide whether the **result** of your command is an empty string, not the command it self. Try

```
while [ -n $(grep -q -F "$username" capstonedata.txt) ]
```

**Edit**

A common error is adding an extra dollar sign when you assign values to variables in shell script. Never use anything like

```
$username=...
```

if you want to assign something to the variable called `username`. Remove the dollar sign before it. On the other hand, you need to use `i=$i+1`

Besides that, I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve by using `username=$username[i]`.

The following script may address your needs or may not, depending on whether I have got your intention right.

```
#!/bin/bash

(cat <<EOF
$username
EOF
)|(while read line
do
        cnt=`grep "\b$line[0-9]*\b" capstonedata.txt| wc -l`
        if [ $cnt -gt 1 ]
        then
                echo $line$cnt
        else
                echo $line
        fi
done
)
```

Since OP has further clarified his need, the script can be made much simpler.

```
cnt=`grep "\b$username[0-9]*\b" capstonedata.txt|wc -l`
if [ "$cnt" -eq "0" ]; then
    cnt=
fi
username=$username$cnt
```

Explanation: `"$username[0-9]*"` matches the `$username`, with optional digits after it, "\b" matches word boundaries (but this seems to only work with `egrep` on some systems although it works perfectly fine on my system, you can use `grep "\<$username[0-9]*\>"` as a safer option) so that you don't accidentally match the line "abcd" when `$username` is "ab". `wc -l` counts the number of lines of matches, so if the username has appeared once, the result will be 1. The back-ticks are used to assign the result of a command to a variable, which is in this case `$cnt`. The `if`-clause sets `$cnt` to empty string if it is 0 (i.e. there's no matching in the file). The last line is just appending `$cnt` to the original user name. So if there is one line that matches the regex the result will be `$username` with a 1 appended. Precisely what you need.

Comment: thank you, the error no longer appears, however the data is not being inserted into the file, when the command is run it just stops after the loop

Comment: There are other issues in your script but since you only mentioned the error in the if statement, I did not modify the other parts. I will modify my answer to address your needs.

Comment: I have realized a few of my mistakes but it still just stops after the loop and does not continue the script 
        i=0
        while [ -n $(grep -q -F "$username" capstonedata.txt) ]
        do
                let i=$i+1
                username=$username$i
        done

Comment: basically what i am trying to do is figure out whether or not there is a duplicate of the username already in the file, and if there is, append a number to the end of it, increasing by an increment of 1. for example if there is a username aaron, the username aaron1 will be created instead of a duplicate. if there is already a username aaron1, aaron2 will be created. I will edit my post with the whole script.

Comment: Since you used `grep -F` in your code, I suppose that `$username` contains more than one line, is it the case?

Comment: $username is a combination of the first letter of the user's first name and the first 4 letters of the user's last name, i have edited the original post with this whole section of the script i'm making

Comment: In this case you don't need a while loop, just take what is in the while loop from my answer, and replace `$line` with `$username`. It should work as expected. Anyway, I will edit the answer again.

Comment: it is giving me an error that an operand is expected where you put the ""

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. Sorry about it.

Comment: instead of creating the username, it sets username to 0

Comment: Use the longer version. The short version is buggy and I will remove it. However, even the shorter version should not return 0. If the username is not found in the file, it should append a 0 to your username (I know this is not what you want but it's very strange that it returns zero), are you missing something?

Comment: i have used the long version and it is not appending the number to the username, it is just adding it to the file without any number. How does this one increment? Thank you for all your help thus far, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will explain how it works in the answer so that you can pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: I suppose replacing `\b` with what is mentioned in the updated answer should work for you. Try it out.

Comment: for some reason, when i check the data file, there is still no number appended to the end of any of the duplicate usernames

Comment: Instead of checking the file, add `echo` statements in your script. In this way you can quickly sort out where the problem is.

Comment: I have found that it is due to the fact that lastName and firstName are not in all capital letters when the username is being searched for, how would i go about converting the strings from lowercase to uppercase right after they are read in?

Comment: Actually, as i tried inputting the information in all capital letters, it still did not append any number to the usernames and I had it echo $cnt and it came up 0, despite there being duplicates.

Comment: Then I will suppose that your file is of some special format and word boundaries in pattern does not apply to your case. Remove them and try again. However, removing them will result in unwanted match like input name "ab" would match "abcd" in the file, I have warned about this in the answer. In reply to your other comment, use `username=$(echo $username|tr [a-z] [A-Z])`

Comment: i have a colon delimiter, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Not really, as long as the character before your `$username` and the one after it can be treated as word delimiters. In your case I suppose the one before it is `:` and the one after it is the newline character. Both of them are valid word boundary delimiters. I have checked my script several times with minimal working examples so I am not really sure what is going wrong on your side.

Comment: My bad, I said you can use an alternative string if `\b` doesn't work for you, but I carelessly dropeed the `$` before "username" in my answer, I suppose that explains why.

Comment: I was able to fix it, but now it says the username with the $cnt, but afterwards on each line of duplicate, it says capstonedata.txt

Comment: oh nevermind, it worked! thank you for all your help, youre incredible!